# Save Gif images in the gallery using code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, gif

I want to save Gif images in gallery in android.
I have tried many time to save gif into gallery but when i press the save button it is download but not in the gif format. I donot know what is problem.

Plz help me to solve this problem

```
public void saveImageToExternal(String imgName, Bitmap bm) throws IOException {
        //Create Path to save Image
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/savaimage1.gif"); //Creates app specific folder
        path.mkdirs();
        File imageFile = new File(path, imgName + ".gif");// Imagename.png

        Log.e("msg", imageFile.toString());

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        Toast.makeText(this, "save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
             bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // Compress Image

            out.flush();
            out.close();

            // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
            // immediately available to the user.
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this, new String[]{imageFile.getAbsolutePath()}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out)` will obviously save PNG file, not GIF.

Comment: also `Bitmap bm` has nothing to do with `gif` format

Comment: okay. how can i save in gif?

Comment: where from do you want to save it?

Comment: I want to save from Json.

Comment: getting images from Json

Comment: show how it looks

Comment: I am getting gif images from Json Using Volley library.

Comment: how exactly they look in JSON?

Comment: Images store in url like as  ( http://greendevteam.website/birthday/images/cards)

Comment: then you are not getting images from JSON, you are getting them from URLs. You just need to save files from the URL.

Comment: how can i save send me code.

Comment: `send me code` this is not how StackOverflow works. You have to try yourself first. You can use search to find that.

Comment: Send me any suggested link.

Comment: What is the problem for you to use search to find it?

Comment: `path.mkdirs();` Your '`path` variable points to what looks a file name. Dont apply mkdirs() on it.

Comment: but issue is not ```path.mkdirs();```